# Regex Directory Name Validation

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I want to check if a textbox have a valid directory name. Because I will create a directory with this textbox value.

Another thing, the value must have at least 3 characters and cannot have more than 20 characters.

How can I do it?

Comment: I would check the length of the path, the simply try to create it and see if it throws an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Path.GetInvalidPathChars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx) is where you can find out which characters are invalid. Rather than use regex, I suggest you use [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) as this will validate the path for you: invariably it will do a better job than anything you will try to roll yourself and will be kept up-to-date as the rules change over time.

As for its length, use the methods of the `Path` class to get the component of the path that you want to check.

Answer (score 3):

No need for RegEx, it's a waste.

```
public bool ValidName(string dirName)
{
    char[] reserved = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();

    if (dirName.Length < 3)
         return false;
    if (dirName > 20)
         return false;

    foreach (char c in reserved)
    {
         if (dirName.Contains(c))
             return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

RegEx isn't particularly efficient and isn't really necessary here. Just check the bounds then make sure the string doesn't contain any reserved characters, returning false as soon as you find an error.

Comment: It could be a good idea to use Path.GetInvalidPathChars() instead of hardcoding the values.

Comment: The `/` is allowed in a path : `/this/is/valid`. And the list of forbidden characters depends on the OS.

Comment: @the_lotus that doesn't quite work because characters not allowed in the path are a subset of those not allowed in a name... You could for example enter "dir/name" which shouldn't pass validation.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal, the `Path` class has another method for invalid name characters: `GetInvalidFileNameChars`.

Comment: @PaulRuane alright, editing with that.

Answer (score 1):

Easy

this is regex you should use.

```
^[0-9A-Za-Z_-]{3,20}$

"^"means starts with the characters defined in [] brackets
"[]" represents list of allowed characters
"0-9" represents that numbers from 0-9 can be used
"A-Z" uppercase letters from A to Z
"a-z" lowercase letters from a to z
"_" underscore
"-" dash
"{}" represents limitations
"{3,20}" - min 3 characters max 20
"$" ends with the characters defined in []
```

if you dont use ^$ than it will search combination of those letters in string so string could be 30 characters and it will be valid.

I hope this helps